# .NET Standard 2.0 Connect to Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to copy some records from a MS Sql Database to a new MS Access file.  Unfortunately, my application is in .NET Standard 2.0 (as opposed to .NET Core or Framework, which would be simple to implement OleDb connection.)  Also, I need to be able to build to 32-bit or 64-bit, so ADOX is not an option.

Does anyone know how I can open a connection to access through .NET Standard 2.0?  Thanks!

Comment: The [System.Data.OleDb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb) package targets multiple TFMs, including .NET Standard 2.0. Note: this is *not* the same as the classes in the .NET Framework's System.Data assembly. It forwards to System.Data's classes on .NET Framework but it has its own implementation for .NET Standard.

Comment: holy smokes, look at that.  Thanks @madreflection.

Comment: is there a way to mark @madreflection's comment as an answer?  If so, please do.  Thanks!

Comment: My comment wasn't quite answer quality. I've expanded it a bit and now it's an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timing couldn't have been better.  Just days ago, as of writing this, version 4.6.0 of the [`System.Data.OleDb`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb) package came out of preview.

It targets two TFMs.  The effect is different depending on which framework your assembly targets and thus which `System.Data.OleDb` TFM is restored for it.

- **net461** - If you target .NET Framework 4.6.1+, it will restore an assembly that has has *type forwarders* to the types in the `System.Data.OleDb` namespace in the .NET Framework's `System.Data` asssembly.
- **netstandard2.0** - If you target .NET Standard 2.0+, it will restore an assembly that contains the actual implementation of the OLEDB provider.

Although .NET Framework 4.6.1 *supports* .NET Standard 2.0, the net461 TFM is more specific so it'll copy the assembly that contains the type forwarders and you'll get the Framework's implementation.